# Seed job repeats building infinitely every minute due to 'job_template' change

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I use jenkins-job-dsl plugin. Created seed job to run `myJobs.jenkins_jobs` file, inside which I have written job `job_template` and another job, which is `using 'job_template'`. However, after building seed job, it continues to build again and again, until I disable it.

In https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-using I see

> Creates a new job configuration, based on the job template referenced by the parameter and stores this. When the template is changed, the seed job will attempt to re-run, which has the side-effect of cascading changes of the template the jobs generated from it.

However, I'm not sure what could I do to get rid of this constantly rebuilding.

My  `myJobs.jenkins_jobs` file looks like this:

```
job('job_template'){
}

job('railgun-db-importer-DSL') {
    using 'job_template'
}
```

**SOLUTION**

The error was that template job had 'description' field updated with date after every run - this caused it to change every run, and run again every run. After putting separate 'description' in every job and hardcoding template job's description, so it doesn't change itself upon run, I got rid of perpetual runs.

Answer (score 0):

**You must not maintain template jobs by job-dsl.**

The idea behind a template job is that you can create new jobs via job-dsl, based on an existing job *that's not maintained by job-dsl* (this is the template job).

Typically, you want to do that if there's some complex plugin configuration which is hard to implement in job-dsl directly -- in those cases, it can be more simple to create a template job *manually*, and use it as a basis for further configuration via job-dsl.

In your example, every DSL run will touch the template job; since modifications of the template job will trigger DSL again, this can lead to the infinite loop that you observe.

Comment: I use template job in DSL to store code that was repeated in all other jobs, to avoid having same code lines in every one job. My impression was, that template job is for having code in DSL script refactored in some extent. Otherwise, if I have job template created manually and rest of the jobs created by DSL, I don't see a point in using DSL, cause I will still have to go and take a look at template job on Jenkins. If I have template job in DSL, I can rapidly check what it contains.

Comment: This is not what template jobs are meant for. For structuring your DSL code, you can use all features and abstraction methods provided by the Groovy language. Creating template jobs in a DSL script and re-using them in other jobs created by the same script is not only confusing but also subject to race conditions. I would not recommend to do that.